# How do you interpret LTSpice graphs?

Tags: ltspice, fan, filtering, power-filtering

I've created a circuit in LTSpice to model a fan assembly I'm looking to build.  In the below circuit the current sources represent the fan and the voltage sources represent the voltage source I'll be connecting to the fan.  Filtering occurs between the two. I'm attempting to prevent the noise from the fans getting on the voltage lines.

[image]

Below is the graph for the voltage between the two inductors, L1 and L3. There are multiple lines because of the step function on C3.

[image]

According to the graph, between 1Hz and 100Hz the voltage is -40dB.  If dB is referenced to 1V this would mean at low frequencies the voltage between L1 and L3 is 10^-2V.  Shouldn't it be 12V? Is there a problem in how I am interpreting the graph or am I not understanding how my circuit works?

---

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

If the AC analysis does not take into account the +12V DC, what exactly is the AC analysis doing?  Is it replacing the the +12V source with a sinusoidal waveform?  I also have a sinusoidal currant draw from AC1.  Is this varied at all with the AC analysis?

Comment: 12v don't exist in the AC analysis..They are only used to get the operation point..Hover any schematic wire after doing the AC analysis and the DC operation point (i.e. dc voltage, current, power) will be displayed at the bottom.

Comment: @tobalt after running the analysis hovering over schematic nets only says "Click to plot V(N###)"

Comment: Yeah I noticed it too. Hmm strange. I am sure, that it is usually displayed there. But I don't know right now, how to get it back there.

Comment: The `.AC` analysis first calculates the operating point for the whole linearized circuit. Any source that is not DC, such as `SIN()` or `PULSE()` will be replaced with their DC value at time=0 (the first value): `I1` will be 1 A, `I2` will be 0 A, `I3` will be 0.2 A. That means any DC voltages may influence the behaviour of the circuit if there are active elements. Since you only have passive elements, any DC will be useless (plus `C1` is completely useless across a voltage source, unless there is some series resistance or you use the current through it).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen ok then after everything is linearized what happens?  Which of the 6 sources would be used as the source of the AC sweep?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen also what about amplitude of the sweep?  I assume it doesn't matter because the dB is relative?

Comment: @timsweeney7 An `.AC` analysis can only be done with an `AC` stimulus, so whatever source has the value `AC X Y` (with `Y` optional, defaults to zero; see the help under *LTspice > CIrcuit Elements > V. ...*) will be the one. If you want to see how a DC voltage affects the result, use a diode, for example. An RLC circuit is already linear. And yes, it's relative to the input source (the `AC` stimulus). See @jp314's answer. If more than one stimulus exists, the effects are cumulative according to the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

12 V is the DC voltage (0 Hz); between 1 and 100 Hz, the -40 dB means the signal amplitude is 10 mVAC (40 dB below 1 V). This is the *AC* component of the signal -- which only makes sense for an AC (i.e. not 0 Hz) signal.

Comment: -40dB is 10mVAC?  And so if I wanted to get the true voltage at any given frequency do I need to add 12V to the AC value?

Comment: yes. -40 dB represents 10^(-40/20) = 10^-2 = 0.01. This is w.r.t 1 V, so 10 mV